# Как создать эффект рыбьего глаза для фона? SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, изображения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность для фонового изображения создать эффект рыбьего глаза ***fish eye*** для фонового изображения?

Пример изображения :

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d0f0f9;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='80' height='80' viewBox='0 0 80 80'%3E%3Cg fill='%231564e3' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M0 0h40v40H0V0zm40 40h40v40H40V40zm0-40h2l-2 2V0zm0 4l4-4h2l-6 6V4zm0 4l8-8h2L40 10V8zm0 4L52 0h2L40 14v-2zm0 4L56 0h2L40 18v-2zm0 4L60 0h2L40 22v-2zm0 4L64 0h2L40 26v-2zm0 4L68 0h2L40 30v-2zm0 4L72 0h2L40 34v-2zm0 4L76 0h2L40 38v-2zm0 4L80 0v2L42 40h-2zm4 0L80 4v2L46 40h-2zm4 0L80 8v2L50 40h-2zm4 0l28-28v2L54 40h-2zm4 0l24-24v2L58 40h-2zm4 0l20-20v2L62 40h-2zm4 0l16-16v2L66 40h-2zm4 0l12-12v2L70 40h-2zm4 0l8-8v2l-6 6h-2zm4 0l4-4v2l-2 2h-2z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Нет, не думаю что `svg` на это способен, смотри в сторону   `canvas`

Comment: @Arthur, Там же `3D эффект`?  Я чего то сомневаюсь

Comment: Но буду рад узнать чего-то новое для себя...  Кстати привет

Comment: Ну помоги человеку...

Comment: @Air, вот не знаю, можно завтра время выделить, сейчас не смогу уж точно. Да и мне кажется через `canvas` точно намного проще будет, так как в `svg` не пробовал(простого решения не будет)

Comment: подождал я чуть чуть и вот ссылка на канвас  с нужным эффектом : https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fish#canvas_geometry_panorama_fisheye

Comment: в общем я тоже голову поломал чуть чуть - и забросил эту идею - всё таки Айр прав - SVG не для этого

Comment: это такое что ли https://codepen.io/jOlga/pen/KyQMQW ?

Comment: При наведении или просто статика?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Именно так как вы хотите создать эффект **[рыбьего глаза](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2))** для фона будет слишком трудоёмкой задачей, но можно создать полотно (canvas), в которое можно загрузить любую картинку, и затем это полотно расположить сверху вместо фона.

**Пример**

```js
var bg = document.getElementById('bg'),
    c = document.getElementById('fish-eye'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
    bgCtx = bg.getContext('2d'),
    src = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='80' height='80' viewBox='0 0 80 80'%3E%3Cg fill='%231564e3' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M0 0h40v40H0V0zm40 40h40v40H40V40zm0-40h2l-2 2V0zm0 4l4-4h2l-6 6V4zm0 4l8-8h2L40 10V8zm0 4L52 0h2L40 14v-2zm0 4L56 0h2L40 18v-2zm0 4L60 0h2L40 22v-2zm0 4L64 0h2L40 26v-2zm0 4L68 0h2L40 30v-2zm0 4L72 0h2L40 34v-2zm0 4L76 0h2L40 38v-2zm0 4L80 0v2L42 40h-2zm4 0L80 4v2L46 40h-2zm4 0L80 8v2L50 40h-2zm4 0l28-28v2L54 40h-2zm4 0l24-24v2L58 40h-2zm4 0l20-20v2L62 40h-2zm4 0l16-16v2L66 40h-2zm4 0l12-12v2L70 40h-2zm4 0l8-8v2l-6 6h-2zm4 0l4-4v2l-2 2h-2z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E";

function loadImg(src)
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function()
    {
        bgCtx.fillStyle = '#d0f0f9';
        bgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, bg.width, bg.height);

        for(var x = 0; x < bg.width; x += img.width)
            for(var y = 0; y < bg.height; y += img.height)
                bgCtx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width, img.height);
        
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', distortion);
        window.removeEventListener('touchmove', distortion);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', distortion);
        window.addEventListener('touchmove', distortion);
    }
    img.src = src;
}
loadImg(src);

document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(e)
{
    var tgt = e.target || e.srcElement;
    loadImg(URL.createObjectURL(tgt.files[0]));
};

function distortion(e)
{
    var cx = (e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.clientX),
        cy = (e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.clientY),
        size = 200,
        zoom = 1;
    
    c.width = c.height = size;
    c.style.left = cx - size / 2 + 'px';
    c.style.top = cy - size / 2 + 'px';
   
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
    ctx.drawImage(
        bg, 
        cx - bg.offsetLeft - .5 * size / zoom, 
        cy - bg.offsetTop - .5 * size / zoom,
        size / zoom, size / zoom, 
        0, 0,
        size, size
    );
    
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, size, size),
        pixels = imgData.data,
        pixelsCopy = [],
        index = 0,
        h = size, w = size,
        i = 0;
    
    for(; i <= pixels.length; i+=4)
    {
        pixelsCopy[index] = [pixels[i], pixels[i+1], pixels[i+2], pixels[i+3]];
        index++;
    }
    
    var result = fisheye(pixelsCopy, w, h);
    
    for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        index = 4 * i;

        if(result[i] != undefined)
        {
            pixels[index + 0] = result[i][0];
            pixels[index + 1] = result[i][1];
            pixels[index + 2] = result[i][2]; 
            pixels[index + 3] = result[i][3];
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}

function fisheye(srcpixels, w, h)
{
    var dstpixels = srcpixels.slice(),
        y = 0;            
   
    for(; y < h; y++)
    {
        var ny = ((2 * y) / h) - 1,
            ny2 = ny * ny,
            x = 0;

        for(; x < w; x++)
        {                            
            var nx = ((2 * x) / w) - 1,
                nx2 = nx * nx,
                r = Math.sqrt(nx2 + ny2);                

            if(0.0 <= r && r <= 1.0)
            {                            
                var nr = Math.sqrt(1.0-r*r);
                
                nr = (r + (1.0-nr)) / 2.0;

                if(nr <= 1.0)
                {
                    var theta = Math.atan2(ny, nx),
                        nxn = nr * Math.cos(theta),
                        nyn = nr * Math.sin(theta),
                        x2 = parseInt(((nxn + 1) * w) / 2),
                        y2 = parseInt(((nyn + 1) * h) / 2),
                        srcpos = parseInt(y2 * w + x2);
                    
                    if(srcpos >= 0 & srcpos < w * h)
                        dstpixels[parseInt(y * w + x)] = srcpixels[srcpos]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dstpixels
}
```

```css
body{overflow: hidden; background: #d0f0f9}
canvas,#button{position: absolute}
#c{border-radius: 50%; pointer-events: none}
```

```html
<canvas id="bg" width="4800" height="4800" style="left:0;top:0"></canvas>
<canvas id="fish-eye"></canvas>

<input type="file" id="file" style="display:none"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Выбрать файл..." onclick="document.getElementById('file').click()"  style="left:10px;top:10px">
```

Вот **[ссылка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlwKt.jpg)** на хорошую картинку для загрузки в этот пример (её надо сначала сохранить как файл).

Код из этого примера был найден **[здесь](https://codepen.io/jOlga/pen/KyQMQW)**, но изначально был взят **[отсюда](https://codepen.io/_massimo/pen/QOaXyy)**.

**См. также:** [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дисторсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Наверно более чистого решения нет, видел все эти ссылки, но мне показалось что должно быть проще, видать нет=)

Comment: @Arthur, куда уж проще?! :-) Здесь обязателен разбор по пикселям – по-другому не получится.

Answer (score 5):

Этот эффект я бы назвал magnifier (эффект увеличительного стекла).

Такой не супер сложно реализовать  а WebGL/GLSL во фрагментном шейдере.

Если убрать весь инфраструктурный код останется этот кусочек кода:

```
vec2 c = uv - m; // текстурные координаты минус координаты мыши
float r = 0.05; // радиус эффекта
float a = dot(c, c); // дистанция от фрагмента до мышки
float f = a > r ? a : a + a/2.0*(a/r - 1.0); // сила эффекта
gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, m + c*f/a);
```

```js
let url = "https://picsum.photos/id/28/650/650";
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
let loader = new Image();
loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
loader.src = url;
loader.onload = function() { 
    
    let z = 1;
    let w = canvas.width = loader.width;
    let h = canvas.height = loader.height;

    pid = gl.createProgram();

    shader(`
      attribute vec2 coords;
      varying vec2 uv;
      void main(void) {
        uv = coords.xy*0.5 + 0.5;
        gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
      }
    `, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

    shader(`
      precision highp float;
      uniform sampler2D tex;

      varying vec2 uv; 
      uniform vec3 m;

      void main(void) {
        vec2 c = uv - m.xy;
        float r = 0.05*m.z;
        float a = dot(c, c); 
        float f = a > r ? a : a + a/2.0*(a/r - 1.0);
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, m.xy + c*f/a); 
      }
    `, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.linkProgram(pid);
    gl.useProgram(pid);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,3,-1,-1,3,-1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true)
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, loader);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(pid, "tex"), 0);
 
    let mouseLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'm');

    gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    
    draw(0, 0);
    
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => draw(e.layerX, e.layerY));
    canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel', e => draw(e.layerX, e.layerY, 
              z *= 1 - Math.sign(e.wheelDeltaY)*0.1));
    
    function draw(x, y) {
      gl.uniform3f(mouseLocation, x/w, 1 - y/h, z);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }
}
  
function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="margin:-10px"></canvas>
```

PS: радиус теперь можно регулировать колесом мыши

PPS: эффект "рыбьего глаза", как и возможность его убрать - [реализован тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988574/188366), так же через `WebGL/GLSL`

Comment: Вот это вы молодец! Не знал, что вы здесь такой ответ добавили! Надо мне тоже начать изучать WebGL и GLSL. А без них сможете такое создать?

Comment: @Bharatha конечно, смысл преобразований то не изменится, только медленно будет

Comment: Мне было бы очень увлекательно такое посмотреть! Если сделаете такое, то дайте знать, я оценю!

Comment: @Bharatha https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/XWKOmYz тут обходятся все пиксели, можно не все а только те что под действием эффекта, будет побыстрее

Comment: Вот это да! Благо дарю вам за этот труд!  Если хотите, то можете ещё добавить изменение свойств как [**тут**](https://codepen.io/_massimo/pen/QOaXyy)

Comment: @Bharatha ну я тут ничего нового сделал, перенес шейдер из ответа на канву, единственное пришлось билинейную интерполяцию добавить, в webgl она есть из коробки, когда считываешь значение из текстуры

Comment: Один фиг тут математику все не понимают, но почему то решили выбрать ответом и заголосовать ответ с меньшей производительностью :(

Comment: @Михаил_Камахин, на время написания моего ответа он был единственным и выбирать не было из чего, кроме него. Смотрите, пожалуйста, внимательно когда были добавлены ответы.