# Убрать эффект рыбьего глаза

Tags: математика, графика, видео, преобразование, glsl

Есть видео с action-камеры, которая при записи применяет эффект типа рыбьего глаза. Область, которая должна быть прямоугольной, имеет несколько скруглённую форму - в сниппете она отмечена красным. Хотелось бы растянуть её обратно до синего прямоугольника. Я могу нарисовать 2 вертикальные или даже все 4 линии, по которым можно определить искажение. Как выполнить трансформацию?

```css
html, body, svg { height: 100%; margin: auto; display: block; }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 171" version="1.1">
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="255" height="170" style="fill:none;stroke:#0000ff;stroke-width:1;" />
  <path style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:1;" d="M 9.2899892,9.8523004 C 0.36470721,58.788143 -1.8968968,109.53857 3.9756332,162.39638 97.464286,177.03692 179.23564,170.77632 254.10649,152.20674 257.52686,105.38064 253.68709,59.452773 242.81437,11.823413 163.07157,-1.6658033 92.718066,-2.2737144 9.2899892,9.8523004 Z" />
</svg>
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то можно использовать фильтр `lenscorrection` в ffmpeg, но я не знаю, как подобрать параметры. Попробовал взять один кадр и поиграться с ним в Gimp'е, но из этого ничего не вышло.

В принципе, меня устраивает алгоритм, а точнее формула, по которой для каждого пикселя нового изображения можно вычислить координаты в исходном. При этом входными данными являются кривые безье, которые я могу нарисовать.

Гарантируется, что рамка будет иметь именно такой вид: 4 ломаных точки с направляющими (в идеале обойтись только двумя вертикальными линиями):

[image: скриншот с направляющими]

Другой пример:

```css
html, body, svg { height: 100%; margin: auto; display: block; }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 201 106" version="1.1" >
  <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;" d="M 1.7008913,10.872024 C -0.67393974,43.547945 0.43942626,72.73567 0.94494026,102.53125 63.525193,106.64485 143.73295,106.1533 200.51635,98.940476 201.24176,66.541427 200.09818,34.516174 195.79166,3.1235117 135.27441,-2.4071433 83.446773,-0.03728631 1.7008913,10.872024 Z" />
</svg>
```

Ответом на вопрос может быть *любой* вариант из следующих:

- Готовая программа, которая выполняет задачу для видео или кадра.
- Способ подобрать корректные параметры для ffmpeg.
- Формула для вычисления старых координат пикселя по координатом на изображении-результате.
- Другое представление графической трансформации.
- ...

Comment: Такое искажение может иметь разную природу, сферическую, параболическую и может что-то еще. Лучше всего было бы взять 1 кадр на котором сфотографирована квадратная сетка. И после применения фильтра/формулы смотреть на результат.

Comment: @Zergatul, образец кадра: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyTve.jpg, кривая скорее всего такая: `d="m 67.94122,30.14881 c -2.170733,31.581695 -1.081358,62.122048 1.181174,92.46243 61.174186,3.00445 145.332886,3.54913 197.728786,-4.016 C 268.68617,86.399109 266.5452,54.430428 262.12649,22.400297 176.83069,17.098953 152.8637,20.456246 67.94122,30.14881 Z"`. Сетки не будет, видео уже есть. Но если всё сделано правильно, все 4 линии колонн должны стать вертикальными.

Comment: @Qwertiy а это место у Вас в зоне досягаемости? Вы можете сделать ещё один кадр там? Без fisheye

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, нет, не могу. К тому же. 1. Новый кадр будет с другой точки и под другим углом - не уверен насколько он оказался бы полезен. 2. Уже есть сомнения, что это всё вообще понадобится :(

Comment: я хотел проверить какие искажения получают колонны в зависимости от центра фокусировки камеры и без рыбоглаза

Answer (score 23):

Это задача может быть решена при помощи трансформации текстурных координат во фрагментном шейдере.

```js
let inputs = ['fisheye:321', 'cX:495', 'cY:334', 'rY:258', 'rZ:562', 'zoom:581']
let input = (id, val) => `<label for="${id}"></label>
<input id="${id}" type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="${val}" onmousemove="draw()"/>`
inputs.forEach(i => inp.innerHTML += input(...i.split(':')))
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
let loader = new Image();
loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
loader.src = "https://i.imgur.com/G9H683l.jpg";
loader.onload = function() { 
    canvas.width = loader.width;
    canvas.height = loader.height;
    pid = gl.createProgram();
    shader(`
        float perspective = 1.0;          
        attribute vec2 coords;
        uniform float rY; 
        varying vec2 uv;
        void main(void) {
          mat3 rotY = mat3(vec3(cos(rY),  0.0, sin(rY)), 
                           vec3(0.0,      1.0,     0.0),
                           vec3(-sin(rY), 0.0, cos(rY)));
          vec3 p =  vec3(coords.xy, 0.) * rotY;
          uv = coords.xy*0.5 + 0.5;   
          gl_Position = vec4(p, 1.0 + p.z * perspective);
        }
    `, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    shader(`
      precision highp float;
      const vec2 res = vec2(${canvas.width}., ${canvas.height}.);  
      varying vec2 uv;
      uniform float fisheye;
      uniform float cX;
      uniform float cY;
      uniform float rZ; 
      uniform float zoom; 
      uniform sampler2D texture;

      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030814
      void main(void) {
        float prop = res.x / res.y;        
        vec2 center = vec2(cX, cY);
        vec2 p = vec2(uv.x,uv.y/prop); 
        vec2 m = vec2(0.5, 0.5 / prop);
        vec2 d = p - m;
        float r = sqrt(dot(d, d));
        float power = (2.0 * 3.141592 / (2.0 * sqrt(dot(m, m)))) * fisheye; 
        float bind;            
        if (power > 0.0) {                
          bind = sqrt(dot(m, m)); 
        } else {                          
          if (prop < 1.0) bind = m.x; 
          else bind = m.y; 
        } 
        vec2 uv = p;                     
        if (power > 0.0) 
          uv = m + normalize(d) * tan(r * power) * bind / tan( bind * power);
        else if (power < 0.0)         
          uv = m + normalize(d) * atan(r * -power * 10.0) * bind / atan(-power * bind * 10.0);
        uv -= vec2(0.5, 0.5/prop); 
        vec2 sc = vec2(sin(rZ), cos(rZ));
        uv *= mat2(sc.y, -sc.x, sc.xy);
        uv *= zoom+1.; 
        uv -= center;
        uv += vec2(0.5, 0.5/prop);
        uv = vec2(uv.x, 1.-uv.y * prop);
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, uv);
      }
    `, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.linkProgram(pid);
    gl.useProgram(pid);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);
    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, loader);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(pid, "texture"), 0);
    inputs = inputs.map(i => document.querySelector('#' + i.split(':')[0]))
    inputs.forEach(i => i.uniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, i.id))
    draw();
}
  
function draw() {
  inputs.forEach(i => {
    gl.uniform1f(i.uniform, i.value/5000-0.1);
    document.querySelector(`label[for="${i.id}"]`)
            .textContent = `${i.value} ${i.id}: ${(i.value/5000-0.1).toFixed(4)}`
  })
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
      return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
    }).join('\n'));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```css
input{width:calc(100% - 190px)}
label{display:inline-block;width:180px}
```

```html
<span id="inp"></span>
<canvas id="canvas" style="zoom:0.6"></canvas>
```

---

PS: после недолгих исследований удалось собрать `ffmpeg`, прикрутив к нему данный шейдер, [подробности тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50591832#50591832)

[код на github](https://github.com/strangerintheq/ffmpeg-opengl)

---

Результат (**не** сильно старался с коэффициентами)

До

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: изменения в сниппете

Comment: Просто кривые Безье в Inkscape нарисовать относительно легко, а задать параметры как-то по-другому - я не представляю как. Но как минимум ты должен использовать центральную точку, относительно которой делается преобразование. Ещё там скорее всего есть какая-то трапеция, если камера не строго перпендикулярна снимаемой поверхности. И ещё потенциальный угол поворота вокруг перпендикулярной оси. Видимо, вокруг всех трёх осей, но одно из них я уже назвал трапецией. Искажение сферическое, но на шар не похоже, по крайней мере, это далеко не половина шара. Я добавил пример в комментарии под вопросом.

Comment: @Qwertiy https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/byzpNJ?editors=0010

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94426/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 3):

Двести лет назад выходила книга про то, как написать свой Wolfenstein. Там была подобная проблема при расчётах: если всё делать по формулам, возникал эффект *рыбьего глаза*.

Чтобы исправить его, автор предлагал умножать расстояние до стены на косинус угла от центра картинки. [Кажется](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173966/raycasting-engine-rendering-creating-slight-distortion-increasing-towards-edges), похожая проблема встречалась не только там.

[image: иллюстрация для дальнейших рассуждений]

Я взял вашу иллюстрацию и чуть её дорисовал, чтобы показать, что я имею в виду. Итак, у нас есть точка A, которая на самом деле должна попасть в точку B.

Если верить формуле, с помощью которой избавляются от рыбьего глаза в алгоритме Raycasting, исправить искажение можно, разделив ординату A на косинус λ, а абсциссу — на косинус φ.

Это углы по вертикали и горизонтали от центра картинки. Беда в том, что они зависят от фокусного расстояния камеры. Камера с коротким фокусом видит широкий угол по горизонтали и вертикали, что и создаёт эффект рыбьего глаза.

На представленной картинке центру экрана соответствуют координаты (0; 0) и положительные направления по осям вправо и вверх, то есть так, как в школьных учебниках.

Мы имеем:

```
yB = yA/cos(λ)
xB = xA/cos(φ)
```

Отсюда:

```
cos(λ) = yA/yB и λ = arccos(yA/yB)
cos(φ) = xA/xB и φ = arccos(xA/xB)
```

Так мы можем рассчитать предельные углы λ и φ.

Теперь сам алгоритм. Вначале вычисляем предельные углы в каждом квадранте. Судя по вашей картинке, камера не очень симметрична и в разных квадрантах изображение может искажаться по разному.

Далее в каждом квадрате идём по всем точкам по вертикали и горизонтали.

В точку B с координатами (xB, yB) мы хотим поместить точку, которая в искажённой картинке соответствует точке А с координатами (xA, yA).

```
xA = xB * cos(φ)
yA = yB * cos(λ)
```

Берём цвет пикселя (xA; yA) в искажённой картинке и перекрашиваем в него пиксель (xB; yB) в целевой картинке.

Теперь переходим к соседней слева точке. У неё угол φ будет чуть меньше. Насколько я понимаю, `tg(φ) = xB/fH`, где `fH` — фокусное расстояние камеры по горизонтали. В идеальном мире горизонтальный фокус должен совпадать с вертикальным, но похоже, что искажения носят чуть более сложный характер. Мы можем считать, что у нас по два разных фокуса в разных квадрантах, рассчитывая, что это повысит точность вычислений в каждом квадранте. Вычислив через `fH` через `tg(φ)`, мы далее на каждом шаге можем вычислять новое значение φ через `fH`:

```
tg(φ') = (xB - 1)/fH
```

следовательно

```
φ' = atan2(fH, xB - 1)
xA' = (xB - 1) * cos(φ')
```

На этой линии ордината `y` у нас остаётся неизменной, но на следующей нам нужно будет пересчитать её так же, как мы сделали это для абсциссы.

Comment: Интересно. Камера-то симметрична (ну или почти, кажется, центр смещён), ты просто не учитываешь третий угол - сама снимаемая плоскость повёрнута. Сложилось ощущение, что ты просто пытаешься вытянуть рамку до прямоугольника, но реально там помимо рыбьего глаза повороты по всем трём осям.

Comment: Кстати, заглядывай в чат: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94426/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-stranger-in-the-q

Comment: @Qwertiy, заглянул. У меня опыта работы с GPU и шейдерами никакого, вряд ли я что смогу путного добавить.

Comment: Там подгонка под конкретный кадр, но довольно удачная. Какой-то универсальной формулой никто не занимался даже.