# Как можно в веб интерфейсе сделать имитацию выпуклого стекла?

Tags: веб-программирование, интерфейс

Я хочу сделать блок на странице, который как бы под выпуклым стеклом. Как если бы это был экран старого телевизора. Т.е. все что находится внутри этого блока приобретает выпуклую форму.

Как можно добиться такого эффекта?
Знаю, что можно сделать canvas в теории, но мне нужно, что бы этот блок был отзывчивым и внутри него, возможно, тоже будут отзывчивые блоки. Т.е. нужно что то, что искажает под собой всё.

Буду рад любым наводкам.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988574/275019   Вот тут решается обратная задача.

Comment: Круто, спасибо! Это очень хорошая наводка.
Вот что еще нашел: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943710/svg-displacement-map-filter