# Некорректно работает увеличительная лупа для изображений

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возникла у меня такая лупа не увеличивает, а наоброт уменьшает изображение (запустите и поймете о чем я) Как это можно исправить?

```js
/* код для слайдера */
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
})
$(function() {

  var native_width = 0;
  var native_height = 0;
  var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  var magnify;
  var cur_img;

  var ui = {
    magniflier: $('.magniflier')
  };

  // Add the magnifying glass
  if (ui.magniflier.length) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'glass');
    ui.glass = $(div);

    $('body').append(div);
  }


  // All the magnifying will happen on "mousemove"

  var mouseMove = function(e) {
    var $el = $(this);

    // Container offset relative to document
    var magnify_offset = cur_img.offset();

    // Mouse position relative to container
    // pageX/pageY - container's offsetLeft/offetTop
    mouse.x = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

    // The Magnifying glass should only show up when the mouse is inside
    // It is important to note that attaching mouseout and then hiding
    // the glass wont work cuz mouse will never be out due to the glass
    // being inside the parent and having a higher z-index (positioned above)
    if (
      mouse.x < cur_img.width() &&
      mouse.y < cur_img.height() &&
      mouse.x > 0 &&
      mouse.y > 0
    ) {

      magnify(e);
    } else {
      ui.glass.fadeOut(100);
    }

    return;
  };

  var magnify = function(e) {

    // The background position of div.glass will be
    // changed according to the position
    // of the mouse over the img.magniflier
    //
    // So we will get the ratio of the pixel
    // under the mouse with respect
    // to the image and use that to position the
    // large image inside the magnifying glass

    var rx = Math.round(mouse.x / cur_img.width() * native_width - ui.glass.width() / 2) * -1;
    var ry = Math.round(mouse.y / cur_img.height() * native_height - ui.glass.height() / 2) * -1;
    var bg_pos = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

    // Calculate pos for magnifying glass
    //
    // Easy Logic: Deduct half of width/height
    // from mouse pos.

    // var glass_left = mouse.x - ui.glass.width() / 2;
    // var glass_top  = mouse.y - ui.glass.height() / 2;
    var glass_left = e.pageX - ui.glass.width() / 2;
    var glass_top = e.pageY - ui.glass.height() / 2;
    //console.log(glass_left, glass_top, bg_pos)
    // Now, if you hover on the image, you should
    // see the magnifying glass in action
    ui.glass.css({
      left: glass_left,
      top: glass_top,
      backgroundPosition: bg_pos
    });

    return;
  };

  $('.magniflier').on('mousemove', function() {
    ui.glass.fadeIn(100);

    cur_img = $(this);

    var large_img_loaded = cur_img.data('large-img-loaded');
    var src = cur_img.data('large') || cur_img.attr('src');

    // Set large-img-loaded to true
    // cur_img.data('large-img-loaded', true)

    if (src) {
      ui.glass.css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + src + ')',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
      });
    }

    // When the user hovers on the image, the script will first calculate
    // the native dimensions if they don't exist. Only after the native dimensions
    // are available, the script will show the zoomed version.
    //if(!native_width && !native_height) {

    if (!cur_img.data('native_width')) {
      // This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
      // We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the 
      // width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
      // created this image object.
      var image_object = new Image();

      image_object.onload = function() {
        // This code is wrapped in the .load function which is important.
        // width and height of the object would return 0 if accessed before 
        // the image gets loaded.
        native_width = image_object.width;
        native_height = image_object.height;

        cur_img.data('native_width', native_width);
        cur_img.data('native_height', native_height);

        //console.log(native_width, native_height);

        mouseMove.apply(this, arguments);

        ui.glass.on('mousemove', mouseMove);
      };


      image_object.src = src;

      return;
    } else {

      native_width = cur_img.data('native_width');
      native_height = cur_img.data('native_height');
    }
    //}
    //console.log(native_width, native_height);

    mouseMove.apply(this, arguments);

    ui.glass.on('mousemove', mouseMove);
  });

  ui.glass.on('mouseout', function() {
    ui.glass.off('mousemove', mouseMove);
  });

});
```

```css
.glass {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: crosshair;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .80);
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.popup-inner {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -100vw;
  right: -100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%
}

.popup__photo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.popup__photo img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%
}

.popup__text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 4rem
}

.popup__text h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #0a0a0a
}

.popup__text p {
  font-size: .875rem;
  color: #686868;
  line-height: 1.5
}

.popup:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999
}

.popup:target .popup-inner {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0)
}

.popup__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -1rem;
  top: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.item {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
}
.item-images {
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto
}
.p1card {
  width: 31%
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.js"></script>
<a class="button" href="#mod"> клик<img class="item-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2hxv.png" ></a>
<div class="popup" id="mod">
  <div class="popup-inner">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="item-images magniflier" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2hxv.png"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="item-images magniflier" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWMhb.png"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="popup__close" href="#s">X</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему фото не отображаются? Подключил же правильно <img class="item-images magniflier"  src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg" >

Comment: У меня из-под фокса увеличивает.

Comment: Только заметил. Если фото маленькое за размерами то лупа увеличивает, но если фото большое (нажмите
На всю страницу) тогда лупа уменьшает. Как зафиксировать чтобы всегда увеличивало?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991010/188366